# Form input checkboxes appearing as text boxes

Tags: html

I am relatively new to HTML and I am trying to build a form. The result I get is this:

[image: screenshot]

However in my code I want a checkbox instead of a text box in the first two cases. And on the last row, the text appearing corresponds to the text of a button. I do not know what I am doing wrong but I would appreciate some hints.

Here is my code:

```
<FORM name=”myForm”> 
<!-- The displayText() function is called when the user checks or unchecks the -->
<!-- checkbox. -->
    <INPUT TYPE=”checkbox” NAME=”graf1box” CHECKED onClick=”displayText();”> Display first paragraph <br> 
    <INPUT TYPE=”checkbox” NAME=”graf2box” CHECKED onClick=”displayText();”> Display second paragraph <br><br> Change third paragraph <br> 
    <INPUT TYPE=”text” NAME=”changeableText” defaultValue=”Type here” SIZE=”35”>
<!-- The changeText() function is called when the user clicks the “Click to change -->
<!-- text” button. -->
    <INPUT TYPE=”button” VALUE=”Click to change text” onClick=”changeText();”> 
</FORM>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Find a new HTML editor please, your code is fine, but your quotes kill it.

Comment: What is the changeText(); function doing exactly?

Comment: This function highlights the seleted paragraphs. I am really sure that the problem does not come from this but for the form sintax.

Comment: I already told you the problem: replace `”` with `"`

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/n70rqg39/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

PLEASE ESCAPE UPPER CASING.

use this code..

```
<form name="myForm"> 

<input type="checkbox" name="graf1box" checked onClick="displayText();"> Display first paragraph 

</form>
```

*and please be careful about the double quotation also*

Hope it helps

Comment: Upper case HTML is unfashionable, but it is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 4):

These frilly quotes: `”` ([U+201D](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm)) are not valid for quoting HTML attributes. Use plain double quotes: `"` ([U+0022](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0022/index.htm)).